# Align end of a text to the bottom of a div

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

I want to create a set of the newest messages that have been posted on my page. Those boxes should always be the same size (as they're in a row, instead of below each other) and consist of three parts:

- Heading (h3)
- Content (no specific tag)
- Author (span)

While it isn't that difficult to keep the heading always at the same position, I couldn't really think of a method of having the author to be **always** on the bottom of the box, no matter how much content there is above.

Perhaps I just think too complicated.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Yea everything sounds good, can we have some code please?

Comment: There you go: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mB5bL/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`position: relative` on the parent box, `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` on the author box.

I won't give you a full solution, because that would not really help.

[CSS Positioning 101](http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101/)

Comment: I knew it, I always think too complicated and don't get any solutions :/ Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use a wrapper set to relative from css and the span positioned absolute
HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <p>Title</p>
  <span class="author">Title</span>
```

CSS

`.wrapper{position: relative; padding-bottom: 1em;}
 .author{position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0`